# would placing a solid rod inside a hollow pipe increase the ability to resist bending?

Tags: experimental-physics

I would like to know if by placing a solid rod of steel inside a piece of hollow steel pipe increase the strength ?

Comment: Placing it how and what strength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it would, but not by all that much. However, the stiffness-to-weight ratio would drop dramatically. At identical material cross sections, the hollow rod (=pipe) will be much, much stiffer than a solid rod.

The axial moment of inertia of a solid rod of diameter $D$ is $\frac{\pi}{64}D^4$, and the one of the pipe with inner diameter $d$ and outer diameter $D$ is (of course) $\frac{\pi}{64}(D^4-d^4)$. In other words, a pipe with an inner diameter that is 95% of the outer diameter has a bending stiffness that is still 20% of the bending stiffness of the solid rod at a weight that is only about 10% of the one of the solid rod.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Take a 6' hollow rod and bang it as hard as you can in the middle against the corner of an eye-beam or such and tell me how much it bends. Take the same rod with the solid insert and hit it 2 times as hard the same way. Let me know your results for how much it bends.